# Sorting and grouping using Office Space API TypeScript in Excel

Tags: excel, typescript, sorting

I am working on sorting using column M in Excel. The column contains strings and doubles but I want to sort the rows based on the double value and not the string. I want to sort the version numbers, which is the double type, from lowest to highest and then put them each in groups that I can expand to see the rest of the objects with that same version value. There are cells in that column that do not contain anything and I would prefer if those were at the top but it is not my biggest concern whether they are at the top or bottom.

This is my script so far. No errors other than when I run it no values show in the specified range

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let range = sheet.getRange("M:M");
let values = range.getValues();

if (values && values.length > 0) {
let versions: string[] = [];
let sortedVersions: string[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  let cellValue: string = values[i][0].toString();
  let version = extractVersion(cellValue);

  if (version) {
    versions.push(version);
  }
}

sortedVersions = versions.sort();

let numRows: number = sortedVersions.length;
let tableRange = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 12, numRows, 1);
let table = sheet.addTable(tableRange.getAddress(), true);
table.getHeaderRowRange().getValues()[0] = ["Sorted Versions"];

let columnRange = table.getColumn(0).getRange();
for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
  let version: string = sortedVersions[i];
  columnRange.getCell(i, 0).getValues()[0] = [version];
}
 } else {
console.log("No values found in the specified range.");
}
}

function extractVersion(value: string): string | null {
let regex = /(\d+(\.\d+)+)/;
let match = regex.exec(value);

if (match && match.length > 0) {
return match[0];
}

return null;
}
```